# Set TextView style to strikethrough in XML only without using background

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm trying to set a TextView's style to strikethrough for a smartwatch app. The ways to do this I've come across so far don't work:

1) Setting the background of the TextView to an image: This works, but only if the text is not wrapped, and I'm getting complaints from customers who have long items

2) Programatically setting the paint flag:

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

I can't do this, as I'm unable to get a reference to the TextView in code due to the way the smartwatch API works (you just send it the layout ID and then you have no control over it)

3) Using HTML tags in the string: Doesn't work, as I'm only allowed to send a string to the control, and it escapes the tags

4) Using a SpannableString: Doesn't work. If I send it using span.toString() then the tags are escaped, and if I use bundle.putCharSequence(span) instead then nothing is displayed.

It seems bizarre to me that you can set bold and italic in the XML, but nothing else. Can anyone suggest any other possible ideas?

Answer (score -1):

When creating custom layouts with various effects we suggest to use `showBitmap()` instead `showLayout()`. You can inflate any layout and draw using `Canvas` into `Bitmap`. For more information, see the `SampleControlExtension` sample. Note, that the disadvantage of this approach will be, that you will need to use `onTouch` events instead `onObjectClick` events.

Comment: Will this still work with a listview though? i.e. would you be able to change the SampleAdvancedControlExtension to use bitmaps instead of standard layouts?

Comment: Lists are a bit special. The SampleAdvancedControlExtension shows an optimization how lists can be drawn effectively. You could still use showBitmap approach but this would mean you need to send the Bitmap for every scroll event, which is not very effective.

Comment: So how can I strikethrough text in my list items effectively?